# Complex equation visualized and interpreted

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[roots complex plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQRWU.png)

The image is showing the solutions to the equation z^n=a for integers a and n. We're supposed to be able to figure out what value a and n must have from the image.

I understand that n must be 4 since there are 4 solutions, and that the magnitude of a must be 16 since each factor has a magnitude of 2. I also understand that since the conjugate of any individual solution is not a solution, that a must be purely complex. So that leaves +-16i as my candidates for what a can be, but the solution says that it must be -16i, and I can't figure out what piece of the puzzle I'm missing. Would really appreciate someone help on this one.

Comment: What's the context? Where did you get the problem?

Comment: Pick any of the four solutions $z$ and calculate $z^4$. What do you get?

Comment: I don't think this is true: "since the conjugate of any individual solution is not a solution, that a must be purely complex"; in fact, this just means that a cannot be purely real. I think you are supposed to read the plot more accurately, noticing that $2e^{\frac{3}{8}\pi i}$ is a root, so a is the fourth power of this, which is $16e^{\frac{3}{2}\pi i} = -16i$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, that would work, I just assumed that since the dots are made to be intentionally large, that we're supposed to figure it out without reading off specific values. It's from a calculus-quiz from an online course, and they only give the answer (-16i) with no explanation

Comment: @mcd I see, that might be a better way to put it. And you might be right regarding the solution, I just assumed that since the dots are so large that we're meant to solve it without reading off specific values.

Comment: Consider the root closest to the positive real axis. Taking powers of the roots is the same as taking multiples of the angle so here we see that four times the small negative angle will not be anywhere near the positive imaginary axis. This excludes the positive solution.